# particular solutions is zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We have some issues with particular solution.

Cannot solve A and B on the last line because it becomes zero all together.
So it becomes $2sin(2x) = 0$

What are we doing wrong? 
Thanks for your time.

$$y''+4y=2\sin2x$$
$$r^2+4=0, r=\sqrt{-4}, r_1=2i, r_2=-2i$$

$$y=C_1\cos{2x}+C_2i\sin{2x}$$

$$Y=A\cos{2x}+B\sin{2x}$$
$$Y'=-2A\sin{2x}+2B\cos{2x}$$
$$Y''=-4A\cos{2x}-4B\sin{2x}$$
$$2\sin{2x}=-4A\cos{2x}-4B\sin{2x}+4(A\cos{2x}+B\sin{2x})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your particular solution should be $ Ax\cos 2x+Bx\sin 2x $

Comment: Since the "frequencies" of the inhomogeneity coincide with the eigenvalues of the homogeneous equation.

Comment: why? where does the $x$ come from? The $x$ in fron of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Basically The particular solution would be $ A\cos 2x+B\sin 2x $ but because this is the form of your homogenous solution you have to multiply through by $x$.